# Angular Controller not console logging data. However, Service is passing in the data.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-scope

I have my backend linked to the service. When I invoke my function on a controller it executes the function in the service and console logs the data. The data from service to the controller is being passed through a promise. I am getting the appropriate data. However, to bind the data on my scope, I need the data on the controller. When I console log the data, I get the console log undefined. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

CONTROLLER

```
"use strict";

app.controller("weatherCtrl", function($scope, weatherService) { //START APP

// ***********************************************
// *************** GET LATEST DATA ***************
// ***********************************************  
    $scope.getTodaysWeather = function() { //OPEN FUNCTION
        weatherService.getWeatherData().then(function(data) {
            console.log("Weather Control", data);
            // $scope.todaysWeather = data;

        });
    }; //CLOSE FUNCTION

    $scope.getTodaysWeather(); //INVOKE THE FUNCTION

}); //CLOSE APP
```

SERVICE

```
"use strict";

app.service("weatherService", function($http, $q) { //START APP

// ***********************************************
// *************** GET LATEST DATA ***************
// ***********************************************
    this.getWeatherData = function() { //OPEN FUNCTION
        var defer = $q.defer(); //promise 
        $http.get("/app/weather/weatherData")
        .success(function(response) { //callback for resolve
            console.log("Main Service Data", response); 

            var weatherDataObj = response.report;
            var weatherDataArray = [];

            for (var key in weatherDataObj) {
                weatherDataArray.push({
                    max_temp: weatherDataObj.max_temp,
                    min_temp: weatherDataObj.min_temp
                });
            }
            console.log("weatherDataArray from Service", weatherDataArray);
            defer.resolve(); //successful promise
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            defer.reject(err);
        });
        return defer.promise; //return promise "q"
    }; //CLOSE FUNCTION

}); //CLOSE APP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"use strict";

app.service("weatherService", function($http, $q) { //START APP

// ***********************************************
// *************** GET LATEST DATA ***************
// ***********************************************
    this.getWeatherData = function() { //OPEN FUNCTION
        var defer = $q.defer(); //promise 
        $http.get("/app/weather/weatherData")
        .success(function(response) { //callback for resolve
            console.log("Main Service Data", response); 

            var weatherDataObj = response.report;
            var weatherDataArray = [];

            for (var key in weatherDataObj) {
                weatherDataArray.push({
                    max_temp: weatherDataObj.max_temp,
                    min_temp: weatherDataObj.min_temp
                });
            }
            console.log("weatherDataArray from Service", weatherDataArray);
            defer.resolve(weatherDataArray); //YOU NEED TO RESOLVE THE DATA
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            defer.reject(err);
        });
        return defer.promise; //return promise "q"
    }; //CLOSE FUNCTION

}); //CLOSE APP
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in `weatherDataArray` to the resolution of the promise, like so:

```
defer.resolve(weatherDataArray); //successful promise
```

Whatever you pass into the resolution or rejection of the promise is what you'll have access to in the `then` function (for example, in your controller).

Answer (score 0):

You `defer.resolve` should have `weatherDataArray` in its function, So that the respective `.then` function will have `data` in its first param.

```
defer.resolve(weatherDataArray); //successful promise
```

Comment: @MihirPatel you have multiple answers to accept..Glad to help you.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `var defer = $q.defer()`, since `$http` returns a promise. Use `$http.get().then` instead of `.success`.

```
"use strict";

app.service("weatherService", function($http) { // removed $q

// ***********************************************
// *************** GET LATEST DATA ***************
// ***********************************************
    this.getWeatherData = function() { //OPEN FUNCTION
        return $http.get("/app/weather/weatherData") // $http returns a promise that we are going to chain, the return statement will return the last promise in the chain
        .then(function(response) { // .then gets the result of the previous $http promise, and creates a new promise (the last one in the chain).
            console.log("Main Service Data", response); 

            **var weatherDataObj = response.data.report;**
            var weatherDataArray = [];

            for (var key in weatherDataObj) {
                weatherDataArray.push({
                    max_temp: weatherDataObj.max_temp,
                    min_temp: weatherDataObj.min_temp
                });
            }
            console.log("weatherDataArray from Service", weatherDataArray);
            return weatherDataArray; // the end result of the promise chain
        });
    }; //CLOSE FUNCTION

}); //CLOSE APP
```